# How to print a List into a table format

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm in the process of learning Java and Have a very simple requirement which I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. A simple ArrayList which writes to console

> FirstName
>
> SurName
>
> Dob

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
myList.add("FirstName");
myList.add("Another FirstName");
myList.add("SurName");
myList.add("Another SurName");
myList.add("Dob");
myList.add("Another Dob");
```

I can't seem to figure out how can I print them in one line i.e

> FirstName Surname Dob
>
> Another FirstName Another SurName Another Dob

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Use `System.out.print(...)`

Comment: SO never fails to surprise me.

Comment: Start by creating an **Object** representing your `Person`. Then store _those_ in your `List`.

Comment: `ArrayList`s don't "write to the console".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

myList.add("FirstName");
myList.add("Another FirstName");
myList.add("John");

myList.add("SurName");
myList.add("Another SurName");
myList.add("Smith");

myList.add("Dob");
myList.add("Another Dob");
myList.add("31/1/1994");

int stride = myList.size() / 3;
for (int row = 0; row < myList.size() / 3; row++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%20s %20s %12s", myList.get(row),
            myList.get(row + stride), myList.get(row + stride * 2)));
}
```

Output

```
        FirstName              SurName          Dob
Another FirstName      Another SurName  Another Dob
             John                Smith    31/1/1994
```

Comment: It actually suggests printing every item but only printing a newline after every third item, not "every other item."

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that the items in the list aren't in that order.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String listItem : myList){
    System.out.print(listItem);
}
```

This is your answer. It will loop around, and each time it goes round the loop listItem will be equal to an element from the list, and it will print it using System.out.print.

Answer (score 0):

If the entries for a single individual were adjacent to one another, you could go through the list printing two items with `System.out.print` and the third with `System.out.println`, but what you really need to do is create a `Person` class with first name, surname, and date of birth fields, a `toString()` method that returns all of those in a single string, and then you can iterate over your `ArrayList<Person>` and print each one out with `System.out.println`:

```
List<Person> people = /* ... */;
for (Person person : people) {
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

Or, in Java 8:

```
people.forEach(System.out::println);
```